# Difference between nach and nachdem

Tags: difference

What is the difference between nach and nachdem and in what instances would you choose to use one over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between *nach* and *nachdem* is similar to *vor* and *bevor*. 
First, they are syntactically different: *nach* is a preposition and *nachdem* is a conjunction. This means that the latter will require typically at least a two-part sentence (for it to be connected by *nachdem*). The preposition *nach* doesn't require this.

Examples carrying the same information:

> - **Nachdem** sie gemeinsam abendgegessen hatten, hat er sämtliche Teller gespült.
> - **Nach** dem gemeinsamen Abendessen hat er sämtliche Teller gespült.

*Remark*: *Nachdem* has to be used with [Consecutio temporum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consecutio_temporum)

Answer (score 1):

[*Nach*](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/nach) is a preposition, and [*nachdem*](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/nachdem) is a subjunction. So, these are totally different word classes. Consider the following examples:

> **nach**
>
> - Ich gehe *nach* Hause.
> - Die Drei kommt *nach* der *Zwei*.
>
> **nachdem**
>
> - Ich sah ihn erst, *nachdem* ich zuhause angekommen war.
> - Ich kaufe eine der beiden Jacke, je *nachdem* welche besser passt.